# Add image to a frame in 45 degree in android from sd card

Tags: android

[image: The image]

the above is picture you can see the white portion i need to include image to that portion  from the SD card.what exactly i need is that the image from the SD CARD should fit to the white space in  the screen(IMAGE SHOULD ROTATE 45 Degree ). How can I include image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is an example [here](http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Working-With-Images-In-Android/3/):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class TestImages extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.test_image);
        Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.test);
        Matrix mat = new Matrix();
        mat.postRotate(45);
        Bitmap bMapRotate = Bitmap.createBitmap(bMap, 0, 0, bMap.getWidth(),bMap.getHeight(), mat, true);
        image.setImageBitmap(bMapRotate);
    }
}
```

for centering the image, I would use relative layout (I have not tested this code but I think It should work):

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
image.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: How can i make the image to center of the screen sam please answer this too thank you

Comment: Hi, I have updated my answer using relative layout. So, do you accept it?